# How to define history region in history output definition for Abaqus Python scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, abaqus, odb

I prepared a Python script to get initial data from a CAE file and modify that for another analysis. To do this, I created a historyOutput command to obtain stress intensity factor and I need to use these values at the post-processing inside of python code, but I have problem with historyRegion definition, could you please give me an advice of why this happen?

Here are the corresponding lines of codes:

## crack tip set

myAssembly.Set(nodes = crackTipNode, name = 'crackTip')

## Contour Integral definitions:

a.engineeringFeatures.ContourIntegral(name='Crack-1', symmetric=OFF, crackFront=crackFront, crackTip=crackTip,
extensionDirectionMethod=Q_VECTORS, qVectors=((v11[7], a.instances['crackedPart'].InterestingPoint(edge=e11[8], rule=MIDDLE)), ),
midNodePosition=0.5, collapsedElementAtTip=NONE)

## Request history output for the crack

myModel.HistoryOutputRequest(name = 'SIF', createStepName = crackStep, contourIntegral = 'Crack-1',numberOfContours = contours,
contourType = K_FACTORS, kFactorDirection = KII0, rebar = EXCLUDE, sectionPoints = DEFAULT)

## Read from history output

crackODB = session.openOdb(name = jobName, path = jobName + '.odb', readOnly = True)
histRegion = crackODB.steps[crackStep].historyRegions['Crack-1']

I put the contourIntegral name for historyRegions, but I get "KeyError: Crack-1" error. I don't what else to do?
Any advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
I had to use 'ElementSet . ALL ELEMENTS' instead of 'ElementSet ALL ELEMENTS', in this line:

histRegion = crackODB.steps[crackStep].historyRegions['ElementSet . ALL ELEMENTS']